# Firefox adds extra space after image in div (or makes divs bigger)

Tags: html, image, firefox, margin, spacing

He everyone,

I have a problem with Firefox on this website I'm working on:

[Link](http://sjoerdbooij.nl/blogNEW2014/portfolios/wedding-abcoude-utrecht-bart-marieke/)

I've built a horizontal slider, which works great on all browsers, except for firefox (both OSX as Windows). The problem is that **firefox shows more margin/padding/space after the images in the slider than the 5px left and right margin it's supposed to have**. Another weird thing is the first image has less spacing than the rest of the images.

I have tried to include a .js workaround with this:

```
function onPageLoad(){
    // Firefox rare spacing fix //
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('.horizItem').each(function() {
            var outerWidth = jQuery(this).find('img').outerWidth();
            jQuery(this).width(outerWidth);
        });
    }, 300);
}
onPageLoad();
```

This works most of the time, but sometimes it makes the divs containing the images 10 or 20px wide. So it messes up the slider.

Is there a simple css fix which I can apply to remove these weird spacings?

**I really can't seem to find the source of the spacing in the element inspector...** When I compare the width of the div to the width of the image, the difference (minus the intended 10px margin) is 15.883px, which is a weird number as well.

Can somebody help me? I feel like it's a real simple mistake I'm making somewhere.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework for something? Guessing by the strange "excessive" width, I think there might be an added padding/margin in percentages somewhere.

Comment: It's a wordpress site and existing theme, but nevertheless I can't seem to find the source... I'm going crazy trying to fix this... Client himself is using Firefox, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similair problem when making Tumblr themes; that images and Tumblr photosets (photos displayed in an iframe) show a little "padding" beneath them, despite the padding being zero in the CSS. The solution was to make them blocks;

```
img, iframe {
    display: block;
}
```

Maybe you could try to display your images as `inline-block`, since they are side by side?

Comment: Thanks, but I already made the img tag blocks, but this doesn't work for me, unfortunately.